# Short sci-fi story about a hellish, industrial isolated domed city, where people live in hypnosis to see it as beautiful

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for the title/author of a short sci-fi story about a domed isolated city where people undergo (without knowing) a hypnotic treatment, to see the city as lush and beautiful, with parks and lots of green, when in fact it's a horrible industrial inferno with fire, heavy machinery and noise. The protagonist starts to see reality when the hypnotic treatment wears off from time to time, making him think he's having horrible apocalyptic visions or going insane, when in fact he's seeing the city the way it actually is, momentarily.

The protagonist seeks help and goes to see a trusted friend, a blind man (who is like a counselor/psychologist). The blind man then consults with someone else (probably from the small elite governing the city) who knows the truth: that the protagonist is not insane, he's not having visions, only that everyone undergoes a hypnotic treatment to see the city as beautiful so as to not live through the trauma of inhabiting a noisy, industrial inferno. The protagonist never finds this out.

The story is none of the following:

- "The Futurological Congress" by Stanislaw Lem.
- "The Mad Metropolis" by Philip E. High.
- "Moongazer" by Marianne Mancusi.
- "The Eyes of the Overworld" by Jack Vance.
- "The Cull" by Robert Reed.

Comment: Hi! Can you provide details about when and where you read the story?

Comment: Yes, read it in some kind of science fiction anthology in the 80s, but it was all old stories, probably from the 50s/60s/70s.

Comment: [The Futurological Congress](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216406/book-story-where-people-are-living-in-a-collective-illusion-and-the-real-world-i)? See also [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/very-old-matrix-like-short-story-based-on-chemicals-released-into-the-air-pre). Though that is chemicals in the air not hypnotic conditioning, and it's a chemist who reveals the truth not a blind man.

Comment: Similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176567/book-about-a-crew-member-staying-on-an-alien-planet-and-marrying-an-indigenous-a

Comment: Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235030/apocalyptic-vr-short-story-where-a-girl-experiences-glitches-in-her-reality?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it's none of these. The story was from an anthology collecting only authors from the US, probably from the 80s, although the story was much older, very probably from the 60s/70s. It's not "The Futurological Congress" or the stories in the above links, although they have similar elements. The protagonist was a man, the population was hypnotized, not drugged or living in a simulated/virtual reality.

Comment: Parts of Jack Vance's [*The Eyes of the Overworld*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eyes_of_the_Overworld) bear mentioning.

Comment: hort story "The Cull" by Robert Reed, humanity has been driven into overcrowded, deteriorating habitats where the population has to be kept artificially happy via implants so they won't notice how bad their conditions are. The implants don't work on some people, so the android doctor expels (culls) anyone who is too disruptive. One delinquent teenager prepares for his cull by stealing items he can use to survive outside. Instead once they're outside the android kills the teenager — it needs the implants inside his head as there's no more being manufactured.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately these recently-mentioned stories are not it either.

Comment: although it is not exactly the same story u might enjoy this short film: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzCQtoQ8ypk&t=161s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it: the story is "Jesting Pilot" by Lewis Padgett (joint pseudonym of Henry Kuttner and C. L. Moore). First published in "Astounding Science Fiction" May, 1947.